# Why does my code give `Structure-return value does not match function type` compile error?

Tags: c

I have code as:

```
typedef struct t
{
    uint8 a[100];

}t;

t tt; //object of the struct
f(&tt); //some file calling the func

//function body in some file
uint8 *f(const struct t *ptr)
{
    return ptr->a;
}
```

When I try to build I get the error:

> Return value type does not match the function type.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that the header file containing function prototype is included and visible to every translation unit?

Comment: try `typedef struct` --> `typedef struct t`

Comment: I would suspect that the `const` is causing the trouble. Does the error message show some more details?

Comment: Yes...its visible

Comment: Then, there is no `struct t`....remember?

Comment: Also use just `t` and not `struct t` in the parameter list as you typedefed it.

Comment: Its generated from Rhapsody. So const struct t is how it generates. Im suspecting the const

Comment: Maybe you need to change the function return type to `const uint8 *`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the name of the type, there is no `struct t` type defined anywhere in your code, so

```
uint8 *f(t *const tt);
```

should be the function signature, of course I suppose you are using meaninful names in your real code.

Also, note that I didn't make the pointee `const` because if you return a non-const pointer to a const pointer to the structure then undefined behavior might happen, the alternative being of course

```
const uint8 *f(const t *const tt);
```

The second `const`, just prevents accidentaly reassigning `tt`.

Comment: uint8 *f(const struct t *ptr) is the function prototype generated from Rhapsody. It is not the problem

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD Then, `struct t {/* definition here */};` is what you need, no `typedef`.

Comment: I think the problem is that i cant return a non-const pointer to a const struct member. If i make the function prototype as struct t *ptr, the code builds.